# How can I make connection between two services in docker swam?

Tags: mysql, docker, swarm

How could I make connection between 2 services: MySQL & OCS in docker swarm the 2 services are in the same overlay network.

Answer (score 2):

Just reference the other service by it's service name with DNS. It should resolve.